# How to create an algorithm to calculate averages

Tags: python, list, mean

I am working on an school project that calculates an average of numbers and compares it to an actual number, for example:
My data is:

```
 heats_chem = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

And my function is:

```
def test(number_of_heats, length):
    all_mean_errors = []
    all_means = []
    for heat in range(number_of_heats, len(heats_chem)-length, length): 
        train_data = heats_chem[heat:heat+number_of_heats]
        test_data = heats_chem[heat + number_of_heats : heat + number_of_heats + length]
        prediction_mean = mean(train_data)
        all_means.append(prediction_mean)
        mean_error = get_error(prediction_mean, test_data)
        all_mean_errors.append(mean_error)
```

With number_of_heats being how many elements to calculate a prediction and length being how many of next elements I am trying to predict. Now I am trying to make a function which does this, but also I am able to use more "windows" of elements to make a more accurate prediction, so I am going to use another parameter called window

```
def test(number_of_heats, length, windows)
```

Now for example with parameters `2,1,3`, it should do `0,1,2,3,4,5` calculate mean, check `2,3,4,5` caluclate mean, check `4,5` and calculate mean, than switch to next one and do `2,3,4,5,6,7` mean, `4,5,6,7` mean etc. but for the life of me I am having the hardest time trying to fit it inside another for loop to be able to do this. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: you want to take a list and split it in 2 in many ways?

Comment: no I want to take windows of 2 a check their mean, and after I have checked in I want to the the same with n+length parameter